# Ionic header image and text not appears on the same line

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to make ionic header image and the text to appear on the same line but the text was placed little bit lower than the image.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
    <h1 class="title" >
        <img class="title-image" src="http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pngtest16rgba.png" height="80%" />
        <span>App Project</span>
     </h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

[Codepen ex](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKgvAG?editors=110)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `vertical-align: middle;` to the `title-image` like this:

```
.title-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This will result it to be vertically aligned with the title/text.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/thepio/pen/kXwOrz?editors=110)

Comment: Then you could just use `.bar .title { font-size: 15px !important; }`. The important is only for the codepen since the order of the stylesheets is not correct. In a Ionic project you could change the `$bar-title-font-size` global variable or set a custom stylesheet to override the default styles.

Comment: there is a small white line appears in-between ionic header bar and ion tabs where I placed ion-tabs on top.. Is there any way to fix this? That thin line appears only on the device itself not on the browser or emulator

Comment: You should ask a new question if you have another problem. But you probably have border set on either the tabs or most probably the header. Try removing the margin.